# how to logged the error_log with php.ini

Tags: php, error-log

PHP5.4

php.ini:

```
log_errors = On
error_log = /tmp/log.txt
error_reporting=E_ALL
```

and now  that code as:

```
<?php
@asdfasdfxxxasdfas();
?>
```

the error can't logged in /tmp/log.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are used [`Error Control Operators`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), from PHP Manual:

> Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable
>   error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script
>   execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to
>   suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available
>   or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no
>   indication as to why.